# Write to file in project directory - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to write/update an existing file called `fileName.json` present in `projectRoot\src\data\database\` directory, from a react-native code present in `projectRoot\src\data\network\dbHelper.js` file.

To read the file, I am using the below code -

```
var data = require('../database/lawyer_data.json');
```

However, to write the file, I tried using `fs` module like this -

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

But it gave the error - `Unable to resolve module fs`

Then I did `npm install fs --save` which gave another error which suggests that `fs` is not meant to be used in React native.

I can't use `react-native-fs` module because it is used to access client-side files. But I want to update files in project development directory.

What should I do?

Comment: you wanna use `react-native-fs` module, then `npm install react-native-fs --save`...Why are you instead `npm install fs --save`?

Comment: @Isaac I don't wanna use `react-native-fs` module because, as explained in the question, it accesses the client-side files.

Comment: You should write a server side endpoint and handle this as an API request like any other

Comment: you can't change content of your app's APK file.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko But isn't it same as updating the database which we regularly do?

Comment: @whodini9 I am a beginner in react-native development. I am sorry but I did not completely get you.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko But isn't it same as updating the database which we regularly do?

Comment: totally different. Database before usage is copied into internal storage o fthe device, where it can be modified